# SSIS checkpoints are not re-starting correctly, skipping NON-checkpointed tasks

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016, checkpointing

I have an SSIS package where the checkpoints are not behaving as I understand that they should.

To simplify, this is the kind of setup:

Imagine a package with two containers in a serial flow (Container 1 executes then Container 2). Checkpoints are configured and ONLY Container 2 is setup as "Fail Package on Failure".  It is desired that Container 1 is ALWAYS completely re-run even in a job restart unless the job made it to Container 2, then it should restart at a checkpoint in Container 2.

Container 1 has a major table copy step that obviously can't be restarted using checkpoints since checkpoints do not track db updates.  So Container 1 has logic that allows it to restart the "old fashion way" by interrogating the source and destination, determining where it left off when it failed, and updating package variables accordingly that are used to drive the main query so it will resume at the row it left off.  This works flawlessly if I delete the checkpoint file after the failure and restart.

I intentionally cause a failure during the table copy in the non-checkpointed Container 1.  But with the checkpoint file left at failure, it doesn't work!  For some reason upon restart, it acts as if Container 1 is also checkpointed.  It does NOT run the steps in Container 1 that will interrogate the source and destination, nor the steps that update the variables and instead immediately goes to the step of the table copy in Container 1, using variable values from the failed run, which causes the copy to start at an incorrect position (and end up with pk violations in insert).  Every task in Container 1 has "Fail Package on Failure" set to FALSE.  They also have "Fail Parent on Failure" set to false in case that matters.  Why does it act as if Container 1 is checkpointed?  Why doesn't it run all steps in Container 1 from the beginning since the package has not even gotten to the first container that is checkpointed (Container 2)?  What behavior am I missing with these checkpoints?